# How to change only one item in ListView?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm making chat app and I have 2 parameters for each message: message text and time when the message was sent, and I redraw these 2 parameters every second.

```
single_message.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

// every 1 second do this
MyJavaClass.java

```
        messagesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ... sending parameters to database and fetch messages

        messages = json.getJSONArray("messages");

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = messages.getJSONObject(i);

            message= object.getString("message");
            time= object.getString("time");

            HashMap<String, String> messagesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            messagesMap.put("message", message);
            messagesMap.put("time", time);

            messagesList.add(messagesMap);
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                        MyJavaClass.this, messagesList,
                                        R.layout.single_message, new String[]{"message", "time"}, new int[]{R.id.message, R.id.time});

                                getListView().post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        getListView().setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
                                    }
                                });

                                setListAdapter(adapter);


                     }
    });
```

How can I only redraw time and that message stays when there are no new messages? Note: User can delete each message at any time.

Also I have problem with scrolling. Since every second I redraw chat and position to last added message, I can't scroll normally, it always return me to latest added message, I can't look old messages normally.
I need to have

```
getListView().post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
              getListView().setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
       }
});
```

because that is the only way to position to latest added message. Latest added messages is at the bottom of the screen as in other chat apps.

And also I have problem with flickering. This is probably because I redraw chat every second. How should I remove flickering?

Comment: It's better to scroll down to last message only when a new message arrives, not every second, just if you **need** to scroll down on new messages. Anyways, from my chats experience, it's annoying when a chat scrolls you down when you are looking older messages.

Comment: Does anyone knows how to fix this? I will pay you if you want.

Comment: First you have to create the ListView only once, and update its contents dynamically everytime you have to do it (new message, message deleted, ...). You can work with the `ListAdapter` object for doing this. UI will refresh after you call `notifyDataSetChanged` method on the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try ViewHolder Pattern (one explanation here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html), with it you can reuse views without redrawing them, and only fill them when necessary